# datenumber: define \dateshortmonthname

Tags: babel, datenumber

I am working with datenumber package with spanish option, `\usepackage[spanish]{datenumber}` and I want to define a command similar to `\datemonthname`, but each month with the first 3 letters, I mean

enero=ene, 
febrero=feb, 
marzo=mar, 
mayo=may,

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three (or more characters) of a string can be extracted with `\StrLeft{somestring}{3}` from the `xstring` package.

I wrapped a macro named `\dateshortmonthname` with one optional argument around `\StrLeft{\datemonthname}{#1}` where `#1` defaults to `3` if not specified otherwise (or not at all).

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}

\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{pgffor} % only for demo

\newcommand{\dateshortmonthname}[1][3]{%
\StrLeft{\datemonthname}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,12} {%
\setdatenumber{2015}{\x}{22}
Current month: \datemonthname~ -- short is \dateshortmonthname

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** The `datenumber` package is quite old and no changes have been made to it since about 15 years.

Comment: “This should be expandable, in my point of view.” I'm not sure what you mean by that, but that's not expandable.

Comment: @Manuel: Right, it isn't. I will remove the statement. Thanks for complaining